# Query associations in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a 'countries' table. when i run a query in a controller action as
"**@country=Country.where(:name=>params[:location])**"

it says

'**undefined method `where' for Country:Class**'
it is working for my states and cites tables. Y so with countries table??

Comment: how did you create the Country resource?  did you run the migrations?  can you show the logs?  can you show relevant code?

Comment: @city=City.where("name LIKE ?", "#{params[:location]}%").first
@state=State.where(:id=>@city.state_id).first
@country=Country.where(:id=>@state.country_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a **Country** model?

**rails-app/app/models/country.rb**

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

A way to test if your *Country* model is working is:

```
$ rails console

> Country.all
```

Should show you all the records in your **countries** table.

Comment: yes i got list of all countries in console. but still no luck with the solution

Comment: When you run `rails console` does `Country.where(:name => 'France').first` work?  If so, the problem may reside in your controller methods.

Comment: even in rails console it says 'NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for Country:Class'

Comment: My best guess is that the **Country** class doesn't inherit from **ActiveRecord::Base**.  Try `Country.superclass` in the console.  It should return `ActiveRecord::Base`.  If it doesn't, check `/app/models/country.rb` and make sure it appears like in the answer above.

Comment: ISO3166::Country 
 is what i get from Country.superclass in console. so i destroyed the model. then recreated the model. by still no luck

Comment: Actually i was using the 'countries' gem for country selection which ws interfering with the actual country model and its inheritance. removed the gem n it started working.
Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Indrajeet Thanks for letting me know!  I was wondering why it wasn't working.  Glad you got it fixed up.